# Change the background view of UITableViewCell for the whole app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have the following method, which works fine for what I want.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIView *colorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    colorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:colorView];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = colorView;
}
```

Now, is there a way to mimic this behavior for the whole app, instead of adding this method to every `tableViewController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Appearance API:

```
[[UITableViewCell appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
```

Most of the time you want to set `UITableView` background color as well, but this depends on your needs:

```
[[UITableView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
```

Comment: You can just use `[UITableViewCell appearance]`.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Where is the best place to add this code? `AppDelegate`? `rootViewController`?

Comment: Either is fine as long as you execute it before displaying any table view. Personally I like to avoid putting too much stuff into the app delegate, if possible.